# How to put UIView inside UIScrollView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, addsubview

I am trying to add a `UIView` into a `UIScrollView` without storyboard. I made some code with the given two files(CalcTypeView.siwft and CalcTypeViewController.swift) as below. However, as shown in the screenshot image, I can see the `UIScrollView`(gray color) while `UIView`(red color) does not appear on the screen. What should I do more with these code to make `UIView` appear? (I've already found many example code using single `UIViewController`, but what I want is `UIView + UIViewController` form to maintain MVC pattern)

**1. CalcTypeView.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

final class CalcTypeView: UIView {

    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        return view
    }()
    
    private let contentView1: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        setupScrollView()
        setupContentView()
    }
        
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupScrollView() {
        self.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    private func setupContentView() {
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView1)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentView1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            contentView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            contentView1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        ])
    }

}
```

**2. CalcTypeViewController.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

final class CalcTypeViewController: UIViewController {

    private let calcTypeView = CalcTypeView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupNavBar()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupNavBar() {
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navigationBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Constant.ColorSetting.themeColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        navigationController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        navigationItem.standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        navigationItem.compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "bookmark.fill"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = Constant.ColorSetting.themeColor
        navigationItem.title = Constant.MenuSetting.menuName2
        
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    }
  
    override func loadView() {
        view = calcTypeView
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    @objc private func addButtonTapped() {
        let bookmarkVC = BookmarkViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(bookmarkVC, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**My Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scroll view's `contentLayoutGuide` defines the size of the scrollable area of the scroll view. The default size is 0,0.

In your code your `contentView1` has no intrinsic size. It simply has a default size of 0,0. So your constraints are telling the scroll view to make its `contentLayoutGuide` to be 40,40 (based on the 20 and -20 constants) and leave the `contentView1` size as 0,0.

If you setup `contentView1` with specific width and height constraints then the scroll view's content size would be correct so that `contentView1` would scroll within the scroll view.

A better example might be to add a UIStackView with a bunch of labels. Since the stack view will have an intrinsic size based on its content and setup, the `contentLayoutGuide` of the scroll view will fit around the stack view's intrinsic size.